# Show that $a^{1/\ln a } = e$

Tags: logarithms

Wolfram alpha tells me that $a^{1/\ln a} = e$ (Symbolab tells me it the LHS cannot be simplified).

Can you help me show this equivalence?

Comment: $a^{b}=e^{b \ln a}$.

Comment: ln(a^(1/ln(a)))=ln(a)/ln(a)=1

Comment: A little unfortunate that the question isn't good enough, but the post [What is the nth root of a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2810105/what-is-the-nth-root-of-a-number) contains an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to convert everything to the same base, and the natural base is $e$. We write
$$
a^{1 / \ln(a)} = \exp(\ln(a^{1/\ln(a)})) = \exp\left( \frac{1}{\ln(a)} \cdot \ln(a) \right) = \exp(1) .
$$
The key fact is that for any real $x$, we can always write $x = e^{\ln(x)}$ since $x \mapsto \exp(x)$ and $x \mapsto \ln(x)$ are inverses.